# with list of objects updating wrongly

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Here is the class

```
 public class CartManage
{
    public int prodId { get; set; }
    // public string prodId { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public string skew { get; set; }
    public string weight { get; set; }
    public string maxqty { get; set; }
    public string productimage { get; set; }
    public string prd_vendor_id { get; set; }
    public string prdDeliveryDays { get; set; }
    public bool GiftingEnabled { get; set; }
    public int GiftingId { get; set; }
}
```

I use this to manage cart in my website i.e **List < CartManage > prodList_temp**. Now when a person increase the quantity of an item in cart. I add another object in the list(I used to just increase the quantity of the object but due to some functionality i have to implement i need separate objects). I did this by doing a linq query on the list and just adding the result to cart.

```
var session_updating_data = prodList_temp.Where(p => p.skew == reqired_skew);
prodList_temp.Add(session_updating_data.FirstOrDefault());
```

The problem im having is that after inserting when ever change anyting in one of the copies the changes are reflected in all the copies. for example i have two quantity of item A, i.e the cart contains two objects containing details of item a created as shown above. Now if I change the giftingEnabled property of any one of the objects it gets reflected in both. Now i found a work around for this by creating a new object. but i would like to know why this weird phenomenon is happening for future reference.

Comment: It is because of this line prodList_temp.Where(p => p.skew == reqired_skew); Actually, it's edit your existing list items and add same copy to your list. Better is to create fresh list item and assign new value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var session_updating_data = prodList_temp.Where(p => p.skew == reqired_skew);
prodList_temp.Add(session_updating_data.FirstOrDefault());`

You are passing a reference to that object to your list, so any change in the object will be reflected everywhere. Where as when you create a new object, it's a separate instance.